# Как мне в Битрикс перехватить данные инфоблока "Обратная связь", после нажатия пользователем кнопки "отправить"?

Tags: php, битрикс, события

В общем-то нужно перехватить отправленные данные. И посмотреть их структуру, однако не знаю как это правильно сделать...

```
AddEventHandler('main', 'OnBeforeEventSend', Array("CRestApi", "generateLead"));

class CRestApi
{
    function generateLead(&$arFields)
    {
        file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/text.txt', print_r($arFields, 1));
    }
}
```

Пытался использовать также *OnIBlockElementUpdate* и др. но ничего не пишется в файл.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно событие перед добавлением элемента инфоблока https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/events/onbeforeiblockelementadd.php (а при записи в файл что бы не было путаницы (где искать) делайте такой путь file_put_contents($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/text.txt'... )